# cut copy paste with DisplayObject(Group ,UIComponent) in action script 3 flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6

I am implementing Cut Copy Paste in my application like [cacoo](http://www.cacoo.com). but I face problem during these operation.
i'm using idea behind cut copy paste

```
var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(objcut.getItemAt(i))
var klass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class
var cloneObject:* = new klass()
```

so i'm not able to preserve all property of object.
**There is any other idea to perform these operation in flex 4.how can i copy an  Graphical object in Flex 4(as3). Copy an Object and paste multiple times.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to make a copy of object with properties is using ByteArray:

```
public static function copy(value:Object):Object
{
    if (!value)
        return null;

    //register object class to prevent Error #1034: Type Coercion failed
    registerClassAlias(getQualifiedClassName(value), value.constructor);

    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    buffer.writeObject(value);
    buffer.position = 0;
    var result:Object = buffer.readObject();
    return result;
}
```

But you can still get the error #1034 for nested classes. You need register aliases for all nested classes to prevent this before making copy, for example in some startup method.

Comment: thanks,but this is not working for custom group componnent...how i register a custom component??

Comment: You can register any class by calling registerClassAlias(getQualifiedClassName(value), value.constructor); where value is your custom component although this utility copy method usually is used to copy simple objects like TextFormat, make a copy of complex visual object can even throw exceptions sometimes.

Comment: i've all visual components,i'm developing a tool like www.cacoo.com a dragramming tool. but cut copy paste of an display object crate problem,

Comment: mxml does not have a constructor so how i achieve this? @fsbmain