# Deep cloning using write byteArray not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm writing a clone function for a class of mine.

```
        var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        buffer.writeObject(this);
        buffer.position = 0;
        var gameblock:* = buffer.readObject();
```

Now at the last line when the time comes to read the object. I get these three errors together:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot
>   convert Object@c60efe9 to model.BlockData. TypeError: Error #1034:
>   Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@c5141c1 to
>   flash.geom.Matrix.

The class 'this' contains a user defined class BlockData and a Point . The errors are coming on that. How do you think I should clone this class?

I do overwrite the BlockData and the point again to make sure they get returned properly

Comment: "better" is for your class to implement [IExternalizable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html) to improve ByteArray serialisation and as fsbmain said, displayobjects can't be copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273989/cut-copy-paste-with-displayobjectgroup-uicomponent-in-action-script-3-flex-4/14276838#14276838) answer for better `copy` method with using of `registerClassAlias` method, but remember, that you can use this method only for simple cases, for example copy of data objects like TextFormat or Value Objects, you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576627/how-to-work-registerclassalias-method-for-custom-mxml-components/14579293#14579293) copy DisplayObject and its successor.